# Menubar not expanding to full width - HTML CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm having a problem in which my navbar is not expanding to the full length it should. Below is my CSS code and HTML/PHP.

## CSS

```
/* Header Layout */

.site-header {
    display: table;
    padding: 0;
}

.site-branding{
    width: auto;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#submenu > ul > li{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 3% 0 3%;
    font-size: 16px
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

#submenu > ul {
    float: left;
}

#submenu > ul > li > a{
    text-decorations: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFF;
}

#submenu > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}


.mainmenu {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    padding-left: .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.header-social {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.header-social > img {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    height: 25px;
}
```

## PHP

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header container-fluid" role="banner">
    <div class="site-branding">

    <?php if (get_theme_mod(FT_scope::tool()->optionsName . '_logo', '') != '') { ?>
            <h1 class="site-title logo"><a class="mylogo" rel="home" href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>/" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"><img relWidth="<?php echo intval(get_theme_mod(FT_scope::tool()->optionsName . '_maxWidth', 0)); ?>" relHeight="<?php echo intval(get_theme_mod(FT_scope::tool()->optionsName . '_maxHeight', 0)); ?>" id="ft_logo" src="<?php echo get_theme_mod(FT_scope::tool()->optionsName . '_logo', ''); ?>" alt="" /></a></h1>
    <?php } else { ?>
            <h1 class="site-title logo"><a id="blogname" rel="home" href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>/" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
    <?php } ?>


    </div>

    <div class="mainmenu" >
        <div class="mobilenavi row col-12" style="width:100%;"></div>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_id' => 'submenu',  'theme_location' => 'primary','container_class' => 'topmenu','menu_id'=>'topmenu' ,'menu_class'=>'sfmenu' ) ); ?>
    </div>

    <span class="header-social">
        <!-- SOCIAL MEDIA ICONS -->
            <img src='<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>/wp-content/uploads/social_images/facebook.png' ">
            <img src='<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>/wp-content/uploads/social_images/instagram.png' ">
            <img src='<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>/wp-content/uploads/social_images/pinterest.png' ">
            <img src='<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>/wp-content/uploads/social_images/twitter.png' ">
            <img src='<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>/wp-content/uploads/social_images/youtube.png' ">
            <img src='<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>/wp-content/uploads/social_images/email.png' ">

        </span>
    </div>

</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

By the way, I'm using wordpress, so the menu is populated through wordpress and not html. [Here is a screen capture of what is happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjXU1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You're expanding "mobilenavi row col-12" to 100% the width of "mainmenu", correct? - If so this is only 750px.

If you want to expand it past this width add to:

```
.mobilenavi row col-12{
position: absolute;
}
```

Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `.mobilenavi row col-12` is intended for mobile only use judging by the name, but the size is being restricted by the maximum width of `mainmenu` (750px) and it seems a fairly large maximum for **mobiles** or tablets only. Media queries can be added to the CSS to so that different screensizes can be catered for, and the width of `mainmenu` can be different for different screensizes, or you can set `mainmenu`'s width to 100%.

Add this to the end of your CSS if you want to use different widths for different screensizes:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 750px) {
 mainmenu { width: 750px} 
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 400px) {
 mainmenu { width: 400px} 
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 751px) {
 mainmenu { width: 1200px} 
}
```